# Valid reason for not having plate armor in early medieval, low-magic fantasy setting?

Tags: magic, medieval, armors, low-fantasy

I'm world building a low-magic, early (to high) medieval (early 12th century-ish) fantasy world for a ttrpg. This world revolves around humans, but -while not something commonly encountered by humans- both elves and dwarves exist. The dwarves, had they be human and would they have lived in the real-world, would have been deemed (mostly) late medieval, with elves leaning into the (early) renaissance. But since this is a fantasy settings, comparing things to the real-world, for anything more than specific slices, such as for this question, quickly goes awry.

**Magic**
Some humans have magic spells, but magic is not commonly available. Those who have magic have dedicated large parts of their lives to learning it. Therefore, magic among humans is rare, awe inspiring, and -for common folk- not uncommonly feared or at least distrusted. Some rulers may be the patron for a 'wizard', but there are certainly no (human) warrior mages or anything like that.

While certainly not everyday common, both the elves and dwarves have a much higher affinity for, and skill in magic. For the elves, magic is a part of their natural world, and magic is used in many parts of their art, culture, and creations (including weapons and armor). Dwarves on the other hand tend to use magic to improve ('imbue'?) their architecture/building, tools, weapons, armor; magic is part of the art of making high-quality things. Magic is still not easy for either elves or dwarves; it requires effort and focus, but both the elves and the dwarves use it (in their own way) for things that are worth to effort.

**Armor**
In this world, the best armor available to human fighting and ruling class should be a helmet, with maille or scale hauberk over gambeson and maille chausses; humans blacksmiths have no method to make plate armor.

However, both the elves and the dwarves have (and can make) plate armour pieces (couters, spaulder, vambraces greaves), with the breastplates exclusively available to the dwarven folk.

**My Question**
This leaves me with a hole in the worldbuilding: within the world as described, what is a logical, internally-consistent reason for why humans would not have access to plate armor?

As this is a world for a ttrpg, when plate armor is exists, players will eventually (at the very least try to) acquire it. While this might be eventually OK for spaulder, greaves, etc., breastplates should be off-limits as player gear. Since players tend to accumulate wealth, 'expensive' on its own will not be sufficient as a method to limit availability to players.

Comment: I believe that plate armour use is rare, historically speaking. So the default kind if you have any kind of maneur warfare is chain mail. Dwarves don't have to maneur so they use plates.

Comment: Depends on the terrains, caves hamper spears and long swords so plate armour is not useful, swampy area also proves deadly for heavyweight units. I once fought a dark elf but was quickly killed because I forgot plate armour is good against physical damage not spells.

Comment: Early medieval plate armor . . . where? Certainly not in Europe. Look at the [Bayeux tapestry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayeux_Tapestry), which is the closest thing we have to a live YouTube clip from the [$\rightarrow$High$\leftarrow$ Middle Ages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Middle_Ages), and count how many knights in plate armor appear. You won't have to use any fingers.

Comment: @AlexP yes, completely true. But this is an early (to high) medieval inspired fantasy setting, where plate armor should *not* be available to humans, while still being available to other humanoids. But also, since the popular notion of 'medieval' is so distorted by movies, common fantasy tropes, and popular culture, I need to brace against the common expectations of people. Which is why I'm looking for internally-consistent reasons, within the given constraints.

Comment: The internally and historically consistent reason is that the technology just wasn't there. Some exotic foreign nations might have recently progressed technologically and economically to the levels required for the adoption of plate armor for some rich individuals.

Comment: Another way to look at this is that the golden days of plate armor was when Europe had population in the 60-100 million people range. In real life, armor wasn't built just to give options to shoppers at the local blacksmith and the idea that you could walk into a pawn shop and find even the pieces of plate armor is a bit laughable. Worse, it was originally the province of nobility (wealthy) until it became the province of governments (wealthy). So unless your adventurers have access to military supply chains in big cities or the nobility in small cities... they simply won't find it at all.

Comment: Also, I removed the [tag:internal-consistency] tag. That tag has a specific use and you're not meeting its expectations. Please read the tag wikis before using them. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to develop a world that stays technologically stagnant for centuries (like most magical worlds), or is this a temporary state that exists at the time of your telling?

Comment: @RobertRapplean It will be mostly technologically stagnant for centuries. With the common trope of more developed ancestors now being a thing of the past. I'm striving for internal consistency on as many factors as possible (but there is also magic, so quite a few of the medieval inspired stuff is far less plausible, if you spend too much time thinking about it).

Comment: What's the goal here? Are you just trying to keep the players from getting too "tanky"? Because the concept of "large metal plates" for armor goes back to the Bronze Age, a good 2 to 3 millennia prior to 1200AD, so it may be easier to, say, improve available weapons rather than restrict available armor.

Comment: @codeMonkey The goal is to keep players within the gear appropriate the early (to high) medieval setting, while still allowing dwarves and elves to have 'later period' (when compared to our real-world history) gear, for various reasons, including signalling their further advanced culture and technology.
This is not about game balance (equipment stats can be tweaked to meet design goals), but rather about getting the feel of the world right, and step away from some of the expectations for a 'medieval' setting (such as fully plate harness 'medieval' knights) that are common in popular culture.

Comment: Can you say whether this is about an early or high medieval setting?

Can you say what 'high medieval' means to you?

Can you say how mere humans would not have acquired dwarvish/elvish technology, whether by trade or, for instance, capturing a few armourers or smiths?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, I could, for as far as the worldbuilding has been completed, but I don't think this is the place to pre-publish 100+ pages of world setting and storyline :-)

Comment: Oh. Of course this is not the place to pre-publish even a single page of world setting or storyline, and who here do you suppose doesn't see, that's not necessary?

Who doubts the answer to '… is this early or high medieval?' is either 'early' or 'high'?

What 'high medieval' means to you won't be Britain in 500  or Germany in 1100 and it might be Italy about 1450 AD.

To how many hundred pages would you spin those out?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin It is a fantasy setting, where some elements lean more towards what, in real-world history, would be classified as early medieval, while other elements (elements that I feel are less important for this specific question) would be classified as high medieval. The dwarves, had they be human and would they have lived in the real-world, would have been deemed (mostly) late medieval, with elves leaning into the renaissance. But since this is a fantasy settings, comparing things to the real-world, for anything more than specific slices, such as for this question, quickly goes awry.

Comment: I don't think you can without a lot of contrived rules. What's stopping a human from paying the Dwarves to make him human sized armor? Your best bet I think is to not give the breast plate a substantial advantage over other existing armors, then the players won't seek it out.

Comment: Why not tell us what 'low' and 'high' medieval mean to you, or choose one, or both?

How do any other of your details help?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[image]

### Humans have not invented spring steel yet

In our own history, humans did not use plate armor in the 12th century because chainmail was a better choice for the kind of steel we could make. The **idea** of platemail goes back to the bronze age, but there is a huge weakness in older styles of plate armor in that you can not finely articulate it.  When you look at something like Roman [Lorica Segmentata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorica_segmentata) for example, it is a form of armor made of articulating plates that would allow minor flexing in the abdominal region, but they could not cover the joints in the hands, elbow, knees, etc. without leaving gaps that a weapon could easily slip into.  Romans were able to craft plates precisely enough to eliminate these gaps if they wanted to, but the quality of steel meant that if they were ever hit there, that the metal would crumple and lock up.

Then between about 100BC and 300AD, Lorica Segmentata was slowly phased out by chainmail, because it impeded movement far less, and it could protect joints without risking locking them up if it got damaged, making it the overall superior (and cheaper) style of armor.

The reason plate armor came back into fashion in the late medieval period was the invention of spring steel.  Spring steel requires a homogenized medium carbon steel and oil tempering to achieve, but in the high medieval period, steel was water tempered.  The issue here was that water tempering does not work well on iron with the carbon content required for spring steel.  Once they figured out the oil thing, they could make steel that was just as hard to deform as before, but it would spring back to its original shape instead of staying crumpled.  This meant that they could make precise joints without having to worry about them getting locked up.

So, in your setting, the humans could have plenty of blacksmiths with the skill to form platemail, but they don't do it because every human knows that platemail is worse than chainmail unless you "imbue it with magic" so that it can spring back into shape when deformed.

### Why a Human can't just buy Dwarven Plate Armor from the local market

> while not something commonly encountered by humans- both elves and dwarves exist.

This implies that very few, if any human towns would have a resident dwarf or elf to make plate armor for them.  Even with this being the case, you'd think merchants would be able to get the occasional trade deal in place to buy and sell armors made by dwarven blacksmiths, but it's not as easy as this.

Plate armor has to be tailored to the owner.  If the length of any segment is the wrong size, it will not articulate properly, and it will be anywhere from very uncomfortable to totally unusable.  This means that a dwarf can't just make a bunch of presized suits of armor and ship them off to sell in human markets.  For a dwarf to make armor for a human, he'd need to live among the humans where he can measure, fit, and alter his work until it is a perfect fit for the wearer.

Since dwarves and humans generally don't live together, dwarves can not make plate armor for humans, even if they wanted to.

From a game mechanics perspective, the tailored nature of fully articulated plate armor can also limit your ability to acquire it from a bad guy; so, you can put the players in a boss fight with a guy in plate armor, but they can not use it once they kill him if it does not fit... and because it is spring tempered, the local blacksmith can't refit it to you without heating it up enough to ruin the temper which would make the joints lock up if struck.

### There may also be a cultural element

In our own history, chainmail replaced plate armor because it was the overall superior design given all the factors at play.  Your humans may be well aware of this fact; so, there's is a good chance that your humans would look down on plate armor under the assumption that it is not good, or not good for the kind of warfare they expect to engage in.

So, even if they saw a dwarf striding along in full plate, they would likely perceive the dwarf as wearing 1000 year old garbage armor that is too hard to move in, full of vulnerable gaps, overheats too easily, etc.  So, even given the chance to wear full plate, your humans may prefer chainmail for military doctrine reasons.

A good historical comparison to this would be the longsword and the katana.  Even though both cultures were aware of each other's swords, they both choose to stick with their native sword styles because these swords matched their own martial traditions, making them each the most effective weapon given their training up to date.

To recreate this as an in-game mechanic, you could give humans access to talents, skill trees, or bonuses that they only get when wearing human armor.  So, maybe your chainmail has a base defense of +4 and platemail +6, but if that +2 defense comes with major penalties or cancels out an even better bonus, then it may be mechanically not worth it for humans to pursue plate armor.

Comment: Re: the dwarf making size 12 suits - IRL buying some clothes or shoes made in Chine might be a coin toss whether it would fit you. Even if they say your size on it. I've seen XXL shirts the size of what I'd consider an M at most. Or shoes that are reportedly size 40 and are *visibly smaller* than a different pair which is also a 40. I've even bought t-shirts from Redbubble which sells stamped shirts. I've ordered *the same size* each time. Presumably they just take the same shirt and put different stamp on it. Well, one reaches below my pelvis. Another barely covers my waist.

Comment: @VLAZ lol, this is true, but with plate armor sizing is far less forgiving than with clothing.    Two people of similar size can wear the same shirt (whether we call it an XXL or M).  Same with chainmail. But platearmor will generally only fit the person it was made for; so, you can't just got to the market and pick the one that fits you.  I could even picture dwarves struggling to make armor for humans and not being able to get the proportions right.  It would be like a human trying to guess how to design form fitting armor for an orangutan, without actually having ever met an orangutan.

Comment: Yes, that was my point. :) If we humans have issues making *standardised* clothing sizes for other humans, then what would a dwarf do :D

Comment: thanks! your answer puts substance to the 'they did not have the technology yet' argument, while also giving very reasonable reasons why they can't plausibly rely on the gear from technologically more advanced humanoids.

Comment: You're wrong about spring steel being needed, certainly for breastplates. The invention of a watermill powered  forge hammer, that could continuously strike with identical force is what made plate possible. And Lorica Segmentata was phased out for economic reasons. Romans got mail(Lorica Hamata) from the Celts, used it extensively in the Republic period, partially ditched it in the high imperial period for the more expensive segmentata and went back to it during the late empire when their economy was a lot worse.

Comment: P.S. the Romans(like the Chinese) has water mills and they also had ornamental officers breastplates, but went with Segmentata for the legions, because plate has to be custom sized for an individual and not suitable to a large professional army. It needed the combination of high metallurgical tech development + all the wealth being monopolized by a warrior elite, like Europe in the late middle ages/renaissance to see widespread plate mail usage.

Comment: And it wasn't made obsolete by gunpowder, but by a shift to mass armies. Napoleonic cuirassier breastplate was bullet proof to a musket at 100 yards. And there are preserved 17th century full plate, with the front being 11mn of face hardened steel(the Mark I tank was 10, with worse steel). But the ludicrous expense of the armor, plus of a horse that could wear it, given the fact that it still did nothing vs a cannon, made it impossible to use for the mass armies of the day. So TLDR plate armor usage is primarily a factor of economics.

Comment: @Eugene No, breastplates are the easiest part to do without spring steel because a breastplate can be dented and remain useful.  That's why breastplates go all the way back to the bronze age, and gauntlets and couters appeared so much later.  It's the little parts that wrap around each other that lock up if they become even a little deformed.  As for Roman armor, there is no historical record of the cost of Segmentata vs Hamata, but thier are written Roman accounts by generals claiming that Hamata was the superior armor.

Comment: Also, modern recreationist report being able to turn out a suit of Segmentata in a week, but riveted chainmail takes hundreds of hours to make. Segmentata was also never adopted across the whole empire.  It seems to have been the armor of choice only against certain enemies who favored heavy warhammers and 2-handed swords that could penetrate Hamata too easily.

Comment: @Eugene Also Cuirassier Armor was certainly not 11mm thick (unless you are counting the arming jacket underneath?).  The standard Cuirassiers' breast plate was about 3mm at its midpoint and tapered out to 1.5-2mm around the flanks and those suits that extended to the extremities were only about 1.5-1mm thick.   And yes, firearms DID make armor obsolete.

Comment: Anything more than about 40kg is too heavy to even mount a horse with, and Cuirassier Armor was already in this weight range, but by the early 1800s, firearms improved enough to penetrate over 3mm of steel making anything close to full body protection a thing of the past.  Today's rifles require 10-15mm of modern alloys to stop meaning soldiers can only protect small parts of thier bodies using armor before it becomes too heavy to carry.

Comment: @Nosajimiki re: breastplates without spring steel, The OP was asking why his dwarves would have breastplates, but not humans, not even dwarves have full plate. Mechanical hammers were necessary IRL to uniformly hammer out something the size of a breastplate, they came before and all the European armorers used them. Classical bronze breastplates aren't a comparison, because bronze can be cast and worked much easier than steel.

Comment: @Nosajimiki re: 11mm 17th c plate: I saw that at an arms museum in Austria. It weighed ~50kg. The guide specifically pointed out that the owner was both freakishly strong(he was like 6'6", when people were shorter) and had the money to purchase it, and the horse to carry it, but was impractical for general use. But 19th c French cuirassier breastplate was expected to stop smoothbore muskets at 100y and pistols at 30. Modern rifles are a bad comparison, much higher velocity, but steel breastplates were issued for urban fighting by USSR in WW2, where mostly pistol caliber rounds were expected.

Comment: @Nosajimiki firearms did not directly obsolete plate, as mentioned, it continued to be used by specialized cuirassier cavalry, and was effective until rifled muskets, but it's expense(both armor and the horse to carry it) + the fact that it did nothing vs cannon, meant no more mass usage.

Comment: @Eugene Yes, a cannon could kill an armored knight if you got really luck, but early cannons were big, expensive, unreliable, and limited in number; so, they saw very little usage early on as anything other than siege weapons.   Cannons and armor co-existed for hundreds of years. What really turned armor into a specialty item was the Battle of Sudomer where 400 untrained peasants with guns killed 700 armored knights and got away.  Armor continued to exist after this point, but only expensive "proofed" armor which was itself phased out like you say by riffles.

Comment: I enjoy answers to fantasy questions that teach me about our own, non-fantasy history.  Really nice.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Knights, like the French Gendarmes, were successfully using full suits of armor(thickened to resist guns in the crucial parts) en masse for a century after Sudomer(1420), throughout the Italian wars. Even thicker 3/4 or 1/2 plate, like the famous parliamentarian "lobsters" in the English civil war,  the cuirassiers in the 30 years war, etc. remained prevalent into the middle of the 17th century, falling off towards the end of the century. The reason it fell out of use by the 18th, wasn't small arms, they didn't penetrate more, but much more accurate artillery with grapeshot.

Comment: @Eugene The Gendarmes were a small, elite cavalry force recruited from the nobility, and very well financed. Making up only 1/300th of France's standing army; so, when I say it was a "specialty item", I mean it was something only a small handful of soldiers had.  Before the 1400s, most soldiers went to battle wairing some kind of armor such as a gambeson or mail which could stop most arrows and glancing blows, but by the mid-to-late 1400s, you see a rapid decrease in rank-and-file armor with most middle-to-lower class soldiers being reduced to just a helmet if anything,

Comment: and most armor that did still exist in the 1400s was not rated to stop a musket.  But guns were still rare enough to justify armor for those willing to pay for it.  By the mid-1600s (50 years before the invention of grapeshot) firearms were already too common and effective for full plate any more; so, the only armored knights you typically still saw past this point were cuirassiers who only wore thick breastplates and helmets,.  Cuirassiers remained a standard cavalry unit right through the invention of grapeshot and into the Napoleonic Wars.

Comment: But the biggest reason not to believe the grapshot hypothesis is that  it was actually the primary role of this cavalry to charge the cannons and make the way safe for the infantry to advance because the cavalry could come in from the side or behind and wipe them out before they had time to readjust thier aim.  If they continued to wear the same armor that was common before grapeshot, and thier main role was to counter such cannons after thier invention, then the cannons were not what undid them.

Comment: The armor they wore was to protect them from the small guns of the cannon crews that could be quickly aimed at them, but once rifled muskets became commonplace, even this last little bit of armor become obsolete.

Comment: @Nosajimiki If you look at contemporary illustrations of the Italian wars(1494 to 1559), or 16th c Geman Landskencht, e.g. https://www.artsy.net/artwork/lucas-cranach-the-elder-saint-matthew you'll see the infantry depicted in (non-full) plate armor. Even by  Rocroi, 1649, the Spanish pikemen still had a breastplate and helmet. My contention is that firearms didn't immediately obsolete armor, but they made the weight/cost vs benefit equation progressively worse. More accurate cannon(in general) plus the invention of grapeshot by late 17th c, which ignored armor completely, was the last straw.

Comment: @Eugene Yes, I think we can agree it was a gradual effect, but I still don't see the cannon as the deciding factor.  Armor was already in major decline before grape shot was invented, and it continued to see use well after it was invented.  The last widespread use of any variety of plate armor was the early 1800s during the Napoleonic Wars.  Even though the cannon became a more important battlefield weapon in this era than before, it was because of its ability to disrupt an enemy line before engaging it.  Most killing, especially of armored cavalry, remained the job of small arms.

Comment: @Nosajimiki During the middle of the 17th century, armor was still in mass use, even among infantry, like I mentioned at Rocroi, but 50 years later was almost completely gone, except for a very few curaissier units. In the meantime, small arms had advanced from matchlocks to flintlocks, which fired faster, but otherwise had the same power. Artillery on the other hand, had gotten a LOT more accurate with the beginning of the scientific approach to artillery, that culminated with it being the "queen of the battlefield" by Napoleon's time. This is what flipped the cost/weight vs protection eqn.

Answer (score 19):

Historically, plate armor as we think of it wasn't invented until the early Renaissance -- during times we'd call "medieval" most armor was mail (aka chainmail), sometimes with small plates attached, or leather with bands, scales, or small plates attached.

This is partly because the art of the armorer-blacksmith advanced over time -- artisans became more capable and inventive as they worked for generations and passed on their knowledge and skills to apprentices.  It's also related to metallurgy; steel making advanced between the 11th and 14th centuries (as well as several centuries before and since).

Finally, plate armor was always *expensive* ("mind-boggling" cost, as one comment had it), the sort of thing only wealthier nobles had any chance of affording (and even they would pass a suit of plate down for generations) -- it required many hours to beat a steel bolster into a large plate; making the plate even and forming it just so took even longer, followed by polishing, riveting or welding multiple layers (at least for the breast and back plates).  The cost of a suit of articulated plate was comparable to that of a small *estate* including a manor house, hundreds of acres of land, and possibly peasant labor (vs. rent-paying tenants).

If you were equipping an army, they'd have been *lucky* to get mail (most would have worn leather or gambeson unless they bought better themselves); only wealthy nobles *ever* had plate, even in its heyday in the 15th century (when it would still stop most bullets).  Plate armor was symbolic of the power and wealth of the wearer; it was never widely worn.

Comment: I thought about the 'expensive' argument, but I think it is not enough of an argument on its own, because players tend to accumulate wealth: 'expensive' on its own will not be sufficient as a method to limit availability to players.

Comment: Plate armor is not necessarily more expensive than chainmail in terms of labor required.  Making chainmail is at least as labor intensive, but the metallurgy required meant you needed a much more knowledgeable and skilled blacksmith to do it well; so, the cost difference had more to do with who makes it than how hard it is too make. If no human in your setting has the skill, then no human in your setting will make plate armor.

Comment: @Jacco you seem to have things backwards a bit. When something is expensive that's not because there are coin operated vending machines that dispense it. And the machines just require a lot of cash. It's real humans that need a lot of time, effort, and expertise to build it. Which means that blacksmiths able to craft armour are not many *and* they'd have a lot of orders. It might take days or weeks to build an armour. If there are 10 blacksmiths total and 100 people wanting armour - some might have to wait for months. And expect to pay a lot for the privilege.

Comment: The "expensive" thing is a brainbug. Articulated  plate was expensive. Breastplates and such were comparatively cheap.

Comment: @Jacco If you're concerned about players accumulating too much wealth and making rare things not rare, then you should tackle that problem at the source. Don't *allow* them to accumulate that much wealth in the first place.

Comment: @Cadence, fair point. This is part of the design goals, but I'm not sure yet how to make it happen (but this issue is not part of this question).

Comment: @VLAZ Your premise is correct, but those time frames are actually very short for armor making.  Without modern tools and prefabricated metal stock, a good, full body suit of armor could easily take over 1000 man hours to make.

Comment: Also to note on expensive, it is hard to imagine how mind boggling expensive they were. You'd have to be a noble and OWN a few hundred people and a big chunk of land to afford that kind of expense. The materials and time neccessary to make them were tremendous. The wealth gap was just so enormous. Most historians I have heard talking on this topic estimated that knights owning a nice full plate armor would have been multi-millionaires in todays wealth levels. And they spend much of that wealth on that armor because it was their life insurance when they went to battle.

Answer (score 6):

### Make metal "Magioative" in large quantites.

For some reason, magic binds easily to iron, steel, and similar materials. If the piece of metal is large enough, it begins to radiate strange, magically-charged effects over time, causing all sorts of ill-effects.

This is a thing that happens passively, with the "magic in the air" binding to large enough pieces of metal. This makes things larger than [whatever your desired largest armor piece] dangerous to wear, as they might cause undesirable effects on those wearing it for more than a few minutes. Small pieces of metal, like chains or coins (or helmets!) don't have those issues, as there isn't "enough metal together" to make it a good "magical sponge".

Magic is weird. Anyway!

This effect is what causes large "chunks" of metal underground dangerous to mine, as miners have to use special protection to avoid being exploded by random magical energies. A dwarf "Cave Wizard" is often employed to disperse those energies safely, so metal can be extracted with no issues. That's what makes them so much better miners than humans, too.

For your elves and dwarves, those magical energies pose no problem - their higher affinity to magic allowing them a greater resistence, thus allowing them to use plate armor without issues.

With the correct circunstances, metal that has been "seeping in" magic for far too long mutate into different, magical forms - silver becomes mithril, iron turns into adamantite, gold becomes orichalcum, and so on. Those forms are far rarer but way more stable, and can be used for all sorts of magical devices.

Comment: I was about to say just "humanity-wide allergies". But yeah, this is the answer.

Comment: This kind of solution has a serious pitfall: not allowing, say, a magical portcullis, which is much larger than a suit of armor. Nor magic wagons (if made with metal), doors for vaults, etc. Perhaps you could get around this with suitable spells which only some people know.

Comment: @MichaelFoster That's a good excuse for having the local wizard at hand.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers recommend technological reasons, but I'd like to suggest a cultural bias.

The dwarves and elves make plate mail, but they do so with industrial processes (magic) that aren't available to humans. The things humans really want can be purchased from other races much cheaper than what it takes for humans to make them. Humans could figure out a work-around for those, but on the rare occasions when people do, it just doesn't catch on and eventually fades from memory. The leap from plate mail to field plate becomes an insurmountable economic jump because the incremental technologies don't leak into the wider market.

Over time, it just becomes common wisdom that humans can't do that, and certainly can't do it at scale, so they don't even try.

Comment: History shows that always somebody keeps trying. This is the most human quality. Elves, dwarfs, demons, can stop trying but humans always keep trying. I don't think this works.

Comment: @akostadinov, Not indefinitely, no, but good enough for fiction. Given the effort that Japanese craftsmen went to when making katanas, there would undoubtedly be prestige items by master craftsmen. Just because humans don't do it doesn't mean that there won't be men who do it.

Comment: @akostadinov Like converting lead into gold.

Comment: @MichaelFoster, I see the humor in your comment and I like it. What I meant with humans never give up is the "ends" not the "means". The difficulties in turning one chemical element into another are well understood. But this is just a means to the actual goal of obtaining gold. And people have invented all kinds of other ways to obtain gold. On the other hand some people still try to prove Earth is flat. So I'm not sure we fully give up on the "means" either.

Comment: There's also the reasonable possibility that our historical field plate could never actually be as good as magically imbued field plate. Metalurgists like to joke about "sword shaped objects," referring to the stainless steel equivalents that you get out of catalogs. To them, our field plate might be an approximation in shape without the functionality of magical field plate.

Answer (score 5):

**Another inconsistency to consider**

With nosajimiki's fine answer of why humans don't have plate armor you got your main issue solved, but you need to solve another inconsistency:

> However, both the elves and the dwarves have (and can make) plate
> armour pieces (couters, spaulder, vambraces greaves), with the
> breastplates exclusively available to the dwarven folk.

If the elves are capable of making plate armor pieces, but don't have breastplates, you need a valid reason for that. Breastplate is by far the easiest piece of plate armor to make - you don't even need a spring steel for it. Even Ancient Greeks had an armor that could be considered breastplate (made out of bronze and thus not all that good). So you need a really good reason why the elves would lack the arguably the most important piece of armor, even thou it should be in their capacity to make. And no, mobility issue is not a good enough reason, as plate armor didn't decrease your mobility all that much. Nor is the weight. If you want to lighten your armor you remove pieces that don't protect your vital organs first.

If you insist on elves having plate armor without breastplates I suggest that the true protection of elven warriors is not in armor at all, but in magical enchantments. Enchantments that are woven into vambraces and greaves for example. And metal breastplate somehow interfere with those enchantments.

Answer (score 4):

### Healing Potions Don't like Steel Plate

Since it's for a TTRPG, I'll assume some kind of "healing magic" is in play.

Make it so healing magic doesn't work if you're wearing steel.

A player can drop their steel helmet and gulp a healing potion, but if they're wearing steel plate, it's going to take 10 minutes to doff the gear, and they better hope they don't bleed out in that time.

Restricting it to steel allows you to use bronze or iron style plate armor - so Roman lorica segmentata is fine, and Ancient Greek bronze cuirass' work. But if you don't want those armors either, you can make the prohibition apply to all metal.

### Topical Ointment

You could also have the healing magic work on contact, and not like steel (or any metal). It's relatively easy to pull up a chain shirt to expose a wound and move the metal in it far enough away for the ointment to work.

But for plate you'd have to remove the whole section of armor, which is harder to do in the middle of combat.

### Exceptions

If you want to have Dwarven plate be a good option, just say its made from a special metal that doesn't prohibit healing magic. Or have the magic involved in making Dwarven armor work with the healing magic so the restriction doesn't apply.

This approach also gives the option of trading better defense for not being able to heal in battle, which I think is an interesting mechanic for a game.

Comment: A fair approach, but in this low-magic world, magic users, let alone healing magic is not commonly available (getting too heavily wounded is a big deal).

Comment: @Jacco - you could make the treatment a "herbal magic" thing instead of a "magic magic" thing. Have it do something relatively minor, but meaningful. (stabilize at 0 hp instead of dying, stop the -1 hp per round bleeding penalty, provide a 40% chance of gaining 4 hp, etc.) Point is, if you give a mechanical reason for avoiding plate mail, it doesn't matter if it's possible in the setting or not - your players (and most other fighters) will avoid it.

Comment: Dwarven / Elven armor is infused with capillary magic that distributes the healing potion / ointment to the appropriate location. Humans can't / don't have the skill to perform capillary magic infusion. If you can afford plate armor you can easily afford healing potions; it's more practical to get hurt and heal than to buy plate if you're poor.

Answer (score 4):

## Laws

Maybe ores that are good enough for plate armor are rare in human lands, and the powers that be want to limit their usage to the making of tools, weapons and smaller armor pieces. Those are easier to reuse among soldiers, since they don't need as much personal tayloring.

Maybe the elves and dwarves subjugated the humans and forbade it. In The Nerdier Scrolls V: Skyrim storyline, the human empire is forbidden from doing some things because they had been defeated in war by the elves and gave up some freedoms in exchange for the right to live.

Maybe it was some other historical reason of your own.

This can lead to some really cool writing because if the prohibition is old enough, the skills involved in plate armour making would be practically non-existent among humans (see other answers on more refined reasons why - the tech for these wasn't even easily available during what we call medieval times). So for the humans to have even a single suite of plate armour, they will have to go on an adventure to dwarven and/or elven lands. They will have a lot of bribing, seducing, cohercing, lying, threatening and negotiating to do before they get the goods.

Comment: I really like this answer. Historically such conditions were pretty common after losing a war. Just look at the contract of versaille after WWI and what germany was allowed and what not by it. And certainly every law is destined to be broken someday.
Also nice character plots of a knight wanting to become a "honoary dwarf" for the right to wear plate armor. Or some quest by an elven king to slay an old dragon and for the duration of the quest that law is put aside.

Comment: If you combine it with the other answer about the difficulties in making good articulated armor, you may well get a situation where the aristocracy largely restricts plate armor to its knights and nobles simply because supply and talent. You want a master cratfts-dwarf skilled enough to make it, AND available steel supply, you better be down with the royal court, because commmon foot soldiers gonna have to put up with the cheap stuff

Comment: A general ban by whomever is ruling is another valid option. Plate is rare and restricted to highest nobility. Until players gain enough political clout they simply can not possess it without significant issues. Consider licenses for modern firearms.

Answer (score 3):

One reason could be simple economics and scarcity. Metal in general and steel in particular is rare, difficult to make and very expensive in a medivial setting. Making plate armor requires a lot of metal and it also requires a lot of training to learn to make a useful armor. The metal used to make a single set of plate armor could alternatively be used to makes knifes or wooden spears with metal points for 100 peasant fighters.

So overall there is very little plate armor in your world and even fewer people who know how to make it. Dwarfs have better access to metal (because they are dwarfs ?!) so the few metal smiths that have mastered making plate armor are dwarfs.

Comment: There is a common misconception that chainmail uses less steel than plate armor.  The average historical weight of chainmail and plate armor is actually about the same.  So, while you may choose to arm about 5-10 peasants (definitely not 100) instead of making a suit of plate armor, the choice between chainmail and plate armor was never an issue of scarcity.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Thanks for the info on chain and steel mail, I didn't know that. I was comparing say 20kg of steel for one set of armor versus 100 times 200g which should be enough for a knife or a wooden spear with a metal tip (no metal armor for the peasant fighters).

Comment: The average medieval spear tip was 300-500g and they often had a metal sauroter or butt cap which would have been another 200-500g to counter balance it.  Also, there are medieval manuscripts and artworks that talk about/show the minimum arms a leveed peasant would have been given, and just a spear almost never happened. Peasants would have typically also been given a metal helmet in the 2000-2500g range and a shorter melee weapon like a hand axe or messer with another 1000-2000g of iron.  So, even peasants typically went to war with 3.3-5.5kg of metal gear.

Comment: I see your point about a spear vs a suit of chain armor, but something as simple as a metal helmet was reported to be a 3x force multiplier when comparing an army given helmets vs one without.  Butt caps are necessary to be able to hold a spear at level for more than a few minutes making them another surprising force multiplier, and spears can't be used in every environment; so, having a backup weapon was a necessity if your enemy tried to exploit your lack of side weapons by engaging you in poor terrain.  So yes, you COULD skimp on the iron, but even the most frugal of generals knew better.

Answer (score 3):

## A process of induction

Dwarves typical living spaces are deep underground, and elves are in trees. Neither of which is good for big smoky cooking fires. So, they invented simple magical heaters. They're one of the few stable, readily available magical items in the world, simple and easy to construct, and they just require attaching to a ferrous plate to heat it to glowing hot, perfect for cooking your dinner in flammable or smoke filled places

Some bastard of a dwarven weaponsmith figured out you could make this ranged with simple modification. One battle against a plate armoured human army, a few stories from the survivors of "The Great Barbecue", and no one wants to go near plate armour. It even brought down the kingdom on the losing side - it turns out that when you crispy fry all the nobles on the battlefield inside their fancy plate armour, the peasants seize the opportunity to take over the kingdom.

So now every ruler sticks to mail and a relatively heat proof wool or leather jerkin. These heat guns have spread widely - they're a favourite tool for arsonists and saboteurs, so even making large iron plates for structural reasons have gone out of fashion. Axes or polearms are also favoured - if a big chunk of metal can get red hot at any moment, you want it on the end of a big stick.

The dwarves make magic induction resistant plate, by layering and breaking up the steel plate with other non ferrous metals. It is heavier, but stronger - perfect for dwarves, but no human can march in it.

Comment: and if you're going for a D&D style campaign, this would be a simple "reskin heat metal as heat ferrous metal, and then make it a cantrip or 1st level spell"

Answer (score 2):

### The Three C's i.e. Culture, Climate and Cost

Lots of non European cultures developed sophisticated armor sets during the medieval period but never adopted the widespread use of *full plate* armor. Look at the types of armor developed in China, Japan, India and the Middle East as templates for your world. Lamellar, laminar (not the same thing BTW - look it up!) jazerant, mail and plate combinations like ' four mirror armor', scale armor? There are lots of technologically sophisticated options. And lots of reasons other human cultures didn't develop full plate armor to the extent Europeans did.

Add in climatic conditions, hot and tropical climates where full plate is simply to exhausting/confining to wear for long periods and perhaps a greater emphasis in human cultures on cavalry warfare and mounted archery as was common throughout Central Asia and you have further reason to avoid heavy restrictive armor. Perhaps the main human cultures and the bulk of the human population also tend to occupy relatively 'open' terrain like plains & steppes, large river valleys and coastal regions of your continents while other races prefer the deep forests and mountains. (Not exclusively mind you - but in the majority of instances?)

Finally Cost: Full plate is expensive and the human societies have large armies to maintain

Also FRAME CHALLENGE: If your humans have sophisticated enough metal working skills to produce other types of armor then there is literally **nothing** preventing them forging/manufacturing full plate armor if they want to, especially since they have the example of and could simply copy Elvin and Dwarfish designs if they wanted to. After all copying and imitation is intrinsic to human culture.

So instead? Yes they *can* produce 'plate'. They just choose *not* to produce 'full plate'.

If you accept this last issue as fact then there is nothing stopping them producing *sections of plate*  that they include as small pieces in other types of armor. They just don't produce full plate for the reason's given. In the time and place your setting? Full plate armor is simply not the best option for them.

Comment: For your conclusion, I would put it "not to produce ... very often." If there is mail and plate, and the ability to do full plate, the occasional knight will spend the money on full plate.

Comment: If a knight or whoever wants to spend the money that's on him/her although in that case they could just as easily order it from the dwarves who are already expert at making full plate than trying to get a human armorer who rarely if ever makes it to have a try. The thing is though the real impact of full plate on the battlefield came from mass i.e. hundreds of men in full plate armor advancing into the foe in a solid mass. One lone dude in full plate mixed up in the battle line? Wouldn't really matter much one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Given that making plate armour is very expensive the dwarves might just have cornered the market with cartel tactics. If ever any human armourer gets good enough they lower prices to drive them out of bussines then jack them up again. The super wealthy and connected can afford dwarven kit and a lucky few are considered friends enough by the elves to be granted armour by them.

Answer (score 0):

**Magic, Fit and Culture**

This is mainly an amalgamation of the other answers.

Dwarves and Elves use some kind of magic to work large plates, a magic that isn't available to humans. This rules out native production of plate armor by humans and adaption of Dwarven or Elvish plates by humans.

Dwarves and Elves have a body shape that's widely different from humans, thus simply aquiring Elvish or Dwarvish plate and putting it on, is out the question. PLate armor needs to fit the wearer, which is in stark contrast to mail.

Dwarves and Elves have strong cultural and/or legal reasons to not produce plate armor for humans. This is the trickiest question in my opinion: why not simply have plate armor made for human by Elves or Dwarves?
You could look at medieval guilds as a blueprint for a legal framework restricting Dwarves or Elves to produce armor for humans, or you might want to come up with a cultural reason, or a mix of both.